# how to solve Spited array

Tags: php, arrays

I have run the for loop in php , i got the following output ... 
I am trying to store 1st value in other array and second value other array... Please any one will guide me to do it !

Or how i can store in two dimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 44
    [1] => 810
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 280
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 279
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 278
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 277
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 276
)
Array
(
    [0] => 87
    [1] => 840
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 275
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 274
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 273
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 271
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 272
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 269
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 267
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 268
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 259
)
Array
(
    [0] => 108
    [1] => 124
)
Array
(
    [0] => 82
    [1] => 239
)
Array
(
    [0] => 221
    [1] => 238
)
Array
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 160
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 161
)
Array
(
    [0] => 65
    [1] => 168
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 169
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 170
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 248
)
Array
(
    [0] => 192
    [1] => 226
)
Array
(
    [0] => 209
    [1] => 222
)
Array
(
    [0] => 80
    [1] => 223
)
Array
(
    [0] => 182
    [1] => 273
)
Array
(
    [0] => 79
    [1] => 183
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 184
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 185
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 186
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 187
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 188
)
Array
(
    [0] => 48
    [1] => 270
)
Array
(
    [0] => 138
    [1] => 190
)
Array
(
    [0] => 191
    [1] => 370
)
Array
(
    [0] => 152
    [1] => 192
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 200
)
Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 210
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 213
)
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 212
)
Array
(
    [0] => 124
    [1] => 214
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 215
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 216
)
Array
(
    [0] => 133
    [1] => 217
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 260
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 285
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 284
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 283
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 286
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 287
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 288
)
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 289
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 290
)
Array
(
    [0] => 76
    [1] => 291
)
Array
(
    [0] => 76
    [1] => 292
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 293
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 294
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 295
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 296
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 297
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 298
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 299
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 300
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 301
)
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Its in For loop then like as followes for($i=0;$i=<sizeof($array);$i++){explod("/",$splitdata)}  So i am getting following output

Comment: Who spit on your array? I'll teach him not to spit on your arrays anymore. No respect! (read your title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
$a = $b = array();
foreach ( $array as $list ) {
    list($a[], $b[]) = $list;
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.org/sVQcWBUs)

Comment: Hey Thanks Buddy its Done , working Fine For me please don't delete the live code..

Comment: ?? What do you mean by `what to do if it is already in one more For Loop`

Comment: You are already `foreach` its better you add your full code to pastbin  or create a new question .. your current issue `how to solve Spited array` as been resolved

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$first = array();
$second = array();
$sourceArray = //this is what you are looping over. 
//Your loop
foreach($sourceArray as $array) {
    $first[] = $array[0];
    $second[] = $array[1];
}
```